# Steamworks API to check if a user is subscribed to a DLC?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, steam-web-api, steamworks-api

My Unity game on Steam has a DLC that is a subscription, how can I check if a user has purchased the subscription but it has expired?

> Using https://steamworks.github.io to perform Steamworks DLL calls.

I've used the `BIsDlcInstalled` method so far but realized it does not work for expired subscription DLCs.

I'd like to avoid redirecting the user to the Store Page and instead have them add the subscription DLC directly to cart or redirect them to the subscriptions page, but right now if I use the `EOverlayToStoreFlag.k_EOverlayToStoreFlag_AddToCartAndShow` flag and the subscription DLC is already owned (but expired), it shows an empty cart.

Is there any other Steamworks API method I can call to solve this issue?